# Writing a Tester Class to test a compiled file

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am trying to write a tester class to test a file that has already been compiled.  I am basically trying to see if the coordinates of are correct when rotated 90 degrees.  I am not really sure how to write a tester class. ANy advice on how to do this?

```
   public static void testRotate90(){
     int fails = SUnit.testsFailed();
     System.out.println ("Testing Rotate 90...");

     CartesianPoint cp = new CartesianPoint();
     CartesianPoint cp2 = cp.rotate90();

     if (fails == SUnit.testsFailed())
         System.out.println("     PASS");
   }
```

Comment: So you at least know the API of the class.  Look into JUnit; that's the standard for testing in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use asserts to compare what you expect the result to be to the actual result. A test fails as a result of either an invalid assertion or calling the fail() method (for instance if you expect an exception to be thrown you might put a call to fail on the line that should not be reached).

You don't have to worry about producing output for the test, the test framework will record what assertions failed for which test class.

Let's say your CartesianPoint class looks like:

```
public class CartesianPoint {
    private final long x;
    private final long y;
    public CartesianPoint(long x, long y) {
        this.x = x; this.y = y;
    }

    public CartesianPoint rotate90() {
        // actual logic omitted, hardcoding result
        return new CartesianPoint(0, 1); 
    }

    public long getX() {return x;}

    public long getY() {return y;}
}
```

Then if you expect to create a point with x  = 1 and y = 0 and rotate it to get x = 0 and y = 1, the test could look like:

```
public class SomeTest {

    public void testRotate90(){
        CartesianPoint cp = new CartesianPoint(1,0);
        CartesianPoint cp2 = cp.rotate90();
        SUnit.assertEquals(0, cp2.getX());
        SUnit.assertEquals(1, cp2.getY());
   }
}
```

For cases like this you may want to test using a number of different inputs, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34756764/217324) for an example of how to write a parameterized test using JUnit.